# Ranking using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function where `f: X × X → Y` where `X` and `Y` are real values, and an RDD `X` of values `a, b, ... ∈ X`.

I need to do

```
Y = X.cartesian(X)\
     .filter(lambda (a, b): a != b)\
     .map(lambda (a, b): (a, b, f(a, b)))
```

For each `(a, b, f(a, b))` in `Y`, I need to rank `b` based on `f(a, b)` for each `a`.

I know I can convert to a dataframe, then use windowing functions in Spark. But is there a more efficient way to do it? `X` would contain around ~10,000 records.